# How do I speed up this EF query?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, entity-framework

How do I speed up this EntityFramework query? The profiler tells me that most of the time is spent in `od.Order` with ~5000 calls.

```
var orderDetails = context.OrderDetails.ToList();

foreach (OrderDetail od in orderDetails)
{
   var date = od.Order.date;

   if (!trPerDay.ContainsKey(date))
   {
       trPerDay.Add(date, od.quantity);
   }
   else
   {
       trPerDay[date] += od.quantity;
   }
}
```

[image]

`Order` property is defined like this:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(OrderDetailMetaData))]
public partial class OrderDetail
{
   public int orderID { get; set; }

   public string productID { get; set; }

   public int quantity { get; set; }

   public bool upgraded { get; set; }


   public virtual Order Order { get; set; }

   public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You're returning all rows from your table with your query. Is that intentional?

Comment: @gunr2171: yes, I'm preparing a lifespan chart.

Comment: @abenci, query just the data you need for the lifespan chart server-side.

Comment: You don't need to load the entire table for that. Write a query that only returns the fields you want. If you want to aggregate and calculate, let the *database* do it

Comment: sounds like an N+1 problem

Comment: @Jodrell: I'm preparing the data inside the MVC controller. What do you mean with "server-side"?

Comment: create a stored proc to get just the data you need for example, eg. let the database server do the heavy lifting.

Comment: @abenci, I mean, do set based operations on the database server. If you can't write queries for your database, apply LINQ operations to your context while it is an `IQueryable`  before you change it to an `IEnumerable` by doing `ToList()`. EF will compose that LINQ into a server-side query.

Comment: Yep. N+1 problem. When you have a slow query, first thing to do, before going to Stack Overflow, is check the generated SQL queries. What do you see there?

Comment: In short, read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/, then read some more.

Comment: What you wrote is a single query executed from a single thread that returns an entire table in a single call. To get 5000 request you'd have to do something very different. Are you trying to access *related* objects perhaps? By default EF loads related objects lazily, ie only when requested. If you try to access 5000 related items, you'll get 5000 requests. The solution is to write a query whose `Select` returns just the data you want

Comment: @Panagiotis: please add an answer with some code. Actually, as you can see I only need a few fields from `OrderDetails` and `Orders` tables.

Comment: You still haven't explained what you want. Eg, `I want to aggregate totals by order date` ?. That's easy to translate to SQL or LINQ.

Comment: Looks like you missed .Include() statement:
context.OrderDetails.Include(od => od.Order).ToList().
It prevents lazy loading and make one db call only

Comment: @BorisR: I was suspecting this. The answer below allowed me to resolve it as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you posted loads the entire `OrderDetails` table in a single query, from a single thread. Then it tries to lazily load each order which results in a separate call to the database.

It's far faster to let the database do the calculations and only load the final results.

In this case it seems the loop is trying to calculate the total order quantity per order date. The SQL query that produces this would be something like :

```
SELECT Date,SUM(details.Quantity)
FROM Orders inner join OrderDetails details
    on Orders.ID=details.OrderID
GROUP BY Orders.Date
```

The equivalent in LINQ can be :

```
var query=context.OrderDetails
                 .GroupBy(d=>d.Order.Date)
                 .Select(g=>new {
                     Date=g.Key,
                     Total=g.Sum(dt=>dt.Quantity)
                  });
var totals=await query.ToListAsync();
```

or

```
var totals=await query.ToDictionaryAsync(t=>t.Date,t=>t.Quantity)
```

In both cases, a GROUP BY query will be generated that calculates the totals by date.

This assumes that `Date` is what it says - a date. Either a `date`-typed field in the database, or a `datetime` without a time component. If it's actually a Date+Time, the query will have to be adjusted to use only the date part. Luckily, EF Core maps `DateTime.Date` to the equivalent SQL function call:

```
var query=context.OrderDetails
                 .GroupBy(d=>d.Order.Date)
                 .Select(g=>new {
                     Date=g.Key,
                     Total=g.Sum(dt=>dt.Quantity)
                  });
```

Comment: This was more then enough: `var orderDetails = context.OrderDetails.Select(od=> new {Quantity = od.quantity, OrderDate = od.Order.date, ProductID = od.productID }).ToList();` Thanks a lot!